# Indexed Sets Problem, union and intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For $_r$ is an element of $\mathbb R_+$, define $B_r = [-1-r,r)$. Determine $\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{R}_+} B_r$ is an element of $\mathbb R_+$ $B_r$ and  $\bigcap_{r\in\mathbb{R}_+} B_r $ is an element of $\mathbb R_+$ $B_r$.

$\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{R}_+} B_r = \mathbb{R}$

For $\bigcap_{r\in\mathbb{R}_+} B_r $ = [-1,0]

Comment: It will help tremendously if you take the time to typeset all symbols using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and $\LaTeX$.  There are unicode some symbols you have used which are not properly displaying (*at least on my screen*).

Comment: Are you asking for $\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{R}_+} B_r$ and $\bigcap_{r\in\mathbb{R}_+} B_r?$ If yes, just write \bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{R}_+} B_r between $\$$'s. And \bigcap_{r\in\mathbb{R}_+} B_r for intersection.

Comment: Yes I am!! @mfl

Comment: @mfl Thank you for assisting!

Comment: That's what I got $\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{R}_+} B_r$ worked out to be.

Comment: What about the intersection?

Comment: All the $_r$ seem to contain the interval (correction) [-2, 1) That's my best guess

Comment: Now how about the intersection.  Recognize that $B_x\subseteq B_y$ whenever $x\leq y$.  What is the "smallest" $B_r$?  Is there a "*smallest*"?  Ignoring that, what then could you describe as being largest number actually appearing in the intersection?  The smallest?  Note: $B_1=[-2,1)$, $B_{0.1}=[-1.1,0.1), B_{0.00001}=[-1.00001, 0.00001),\dots$.  Note also that $0$ is not technically positive, so $B_0$ is not in fact one of the sets in the family which you are intersecting, however $B_\epsilon$ is for every small $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: It seems to be close to [-1,0) but not exactly since 0 is not a positive $ \mathbb R $

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for assisting and helping me think through the problem. What would be the best way to write the answer to $\bigcap_{r\in\mathbb{R}_+} B_r $ out?

Comment: I don't quite fully understand the last part of what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $B_x\subseteq B_y$ whenever $x\leq y$, so the family of sets are what we call "*nested*", meaning that if there was a "*smallest*" set in our family, the intersection over the entire family would simply be that smallest set.

In our case, however, there is no "*smallest*" but it can still give us some intuition as to what is going on.  If we were indexing over all non-negative (zero included) sets, then the smallest would have been $B_0 = [-1,0)$.

Since zero is not one of the values over which we are indexing, notice then that $B_\epsilon = [-1-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon>0$ and in particular then that $0\in [-1-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.

---

Steps to complete:

- Prove that $[-1,0]\subseteq B_r$ for all $r\in \Bbb R^+$
- Prove that any $x\in \left(\Bbb R\setminus [-1,0]\right)$ has at least one $r$ for which $x\notin B_r$
- Use the definition of intersection over a family to conclude that $\bigcap\limits_{r\in \Bbb R^+} B_r = [-1,0]$